# Angular js съехала верстка html

Tags: html, angular

Вот кусочек верстки, представляющий собой "пагинацию". Решила с jquery переписать на angular, чтобы красивей было, но все поломалось

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <nav aria-label="Page navigation" class="mb-2" id="pageNavigation">
                        <h6><label for="pageNavigation">Page navigation</label></h6>
                        <ul class="pagination" id="navigation" ng-repeat="page in pages">
                            <li ng-class="page == severResponse.page ?  'page-item active' : 'page-item'">
                                <a class="page-link" ng-click="switchPage($index)">{{page}}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <nav aria-label="Page navigation" id="pageSize">
                        <h6><label for="pageSize">Page size</label></h6>
                        <ul class="pagination" id="size" ng-repeat="size in sizes">
                            <li ng-class="size == severResponse.size ?  'page-item active' : 'page-item'">
                                <a class="page-link" ng-click="switchSize($index)">{{size}}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

А это кусочек jquery:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                <nav aria-label="Page navigation" class="mb-2" id="pageNavigation">
                    <h6><label for="pageNavigation">Page navigation</label></h6>
                    <ul class="pagination" id="navigation">
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                <nav aria-label="Page navigation" id="pageSize">
                    <h6><label for="pageSize">Page size</label></h6>
                    <ul class="pagination" id="size">
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Заполняется он уже так:

```
$("#size").html(...)
```

Вот что с jquery:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Angular:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дело не в ангуляре, а скорее всего в том, что вы забыли подключить к проекту bootstrap (если судить по классам)

Comment: нет, бутстрап подключен. Это просто кусок разметки, чобы не пихать лишнего - `<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: Как вы подключили bootstrap к проекту на angular? В styles.css указали @import?

Comment: не понел. Как всегда, по ссылке в шапке 0_о (и там и там)

Comment: Попробуйте так: https://loiane.com/2017/08/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project/